# How to do a git push using ansible

Tags: configuration, ansible, git, configuration-management

I'm using Ansible

to make a pull i do this

```
tasks:
    - name: pull from git
      git:
        repo: git@gitlab.com:xyz.git
        dest: /root/Development/abc
        update: yes
        version: master
```

Note: Here the remote user is root

My question is how can i do a push with `git ansible` module ?

Answer (score 1):

> how can I do a push with git ansible module ?

The built in git module doesn't have that functionality. It is focused pulling down code so it can be built.